# Is there a way how to share data or monitor progress of a complex PostgresSQL transaction?

Tags: postgresql

We have a long running operation (~15mins) which creates something between 100 000 and 1 million validation rows. It is implemented as a stored procedure and because we don't want to end up with a partial validation result the whole validation is 1 transaction.

Is there a way how to monitor the progress of the validation operation? In other words, is there a way how to see from outside of this transaction how many rows were already generated. Or any other indication about the calculation progress?

Comment: Not directly no. Obviously from outside the transaction the changes don't actually exist. If your stored-procedure is looping you can use `RAISE NOTICE` or similar to print out a count of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DBLink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/dblink.html) can be used to perform `UPDATE`s on a progress table that a client polls. A more advanced method would be to use DBLink to call [`NOTIFY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-notify.html) to send progress updates to a client that supports asynchronous notifications (e.g., client code written in C).

A combination approach could also be used so that the client queries the progress table to get structured details whenever it receives notifications.